# Unable to install Xcode 4.3.2 on Mac OS x Lion 10.7.4

Tags: macos, mac, xcode

I tried to install Xcode 4.3.2 from application store, after clicking the Install button, a message displayed as "Installing". (but no progress bar appeared)

After about 30 minutes, (while installation was on progress), my Mac crashed and I had to turn off the power and restart it again.

Now, if I try to install the Xcode again, nothing happens (see the image) after I click the install button except the Apple store login dialog pops in and ask to login.

(No folder named "Developer" has been created in my Application folder yet)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: Xcode couldn't be installed using the App Store. It might be related to having had an earlier version of Xcode installed.

I solved the problem by downloading Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/resources/ . Click on *Mac OS X Downloads* and enter your credentials (free; not required to be member of OS X developer program), and select *Xcode 4.3.2 for Lion* from the list.

With this version of Xcode, it was changed from an installer bundle distribution, installing to `/Developer` to an actual app, installed to `/Applications`. Things like developer documentation or command line tools must be installed from Xcode preferences.

Comment: But my machine is a brand new one, with no previous installation.

Comment: If you install like this manually, is it possible to update it through Apple store?

Comment: I don't know. 4.3.2 is the most recent version. Given the choice between Xcode needing manual updates, and no Xcode, I choose the former.

Answer (score 1):

But, latter I found an icon named "paused" in the **2nd** page of my **Launchpad**. When clicking, installation simply started and completed without any problems.

The icon contains a tiny progress bar as well.

[image]

Comment: A had the same problem. This seems to have fixed it for me (Still waiting to see if it finishes). Thanks!